# Json with data inconsistency

Tags: c#, arrays, json, object

I got this strange API response from one external service:

```
{emplooye: "Michael",age:"25",attachments:[{idAttachment: "23",attachmentPath:"C://Users/1"},{idAttachment: "24",attachmentPath:"C://Users/2"}]},{emplooye: "John",age:"30",attachments:{idAttachment: "25",attachmentPath:"C://Users/3"}}
```

Has anyone ever faced a situation where sometimes the "Attachment" property can be an array, sometimes it can be an object? I created a class to manipulate the data, but when I find an object, the code breaks.
I'm doing this in C#.

Class Used

```
public class Attachments
    {
        public string idAttachment{ get; set; }
        public string attachmentPath{ get; set; }
    }

public class Root
{
    public string emplooye {get; set;}
    public string age {get;set}
    public List<Attachments> attachments { get; set; } = new List<Attachments>();
}
```

Comment: Have you consulted with the service you're obtaining this JSON from to determine why the schema changes?

Comment: Yes @gunr2171, and I was informed that this will not change :(

Comment: Can you also provide the Class model you are working with?

Comment: @Izanagi Yes, I edited the post containing the classes used.

Comment: Your json is not valid and can not be parsed. Contact API service

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your json is not even close to json, should be something like this

```
var json = "[{\"emplooye\":\"Michael\",\"age\":\"25\",\"attachments\":[{\"idAttachment\":\"23\",\"attachmentPath\":\"C://Users/1\"},{\"idAttachment\":\"24\",\"attachmentPath\":\"C://Users/2\"}]},{\"emplooye\":\"John\",\"age\":\"30\",\"attachments\":{\"idAttachment\":\"25\",\"attachmentPath\":\"C://Users/3\"}}]";
```

Using Newtonsoft.Json you can create a JsonConstructor

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

List<Data> data= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Data>>(json);
 

public class Data
{
    public string emplooye { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
    public List<Attachments> attachments { get; set; }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public Data(JToken attachments)
    {
        if (attachments.Type.ToString() == "Array") 
            this.attachments = attachments.ToObject<List<Attachments>>();
        else
            this.attachments = new List<Attachments> { attachments.ToObject<Attachments>() };
    }
    public Data() {}
}

public class Attachments
{
    public string idAttachment { get; set; }
    public string attachmentPath { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Even though the mentions snippet is not JSON, it's still a valid JavaScript literal and NewtonSoft.Json supports unquoted property names. However, you wrapped the object in an array, which is not the use case here. Otherwise, I like your answer, but I don't know what the `Dump` extension method does, but I don't think that line does anything. I'd also rather use the `JTokenType ` for comparison rather than converting to string.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde It is a not valid javascript object too, since it  doesn't have a root   You are very welcome to post your own solution. JTokenType  is just a mater of style

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't have a root? The root is an object. Wrapping it in an array doesn't make it any more JSON, and it's dangerous too!

Comment: Also, comparing the enum directly is not about style, it's about performance and sets a bad example.

Comment: @DaveVandenEynde I recommend you to learn object the next time before critisizing.  If you had looked at  OP json, you would see that the first json object is followed by the second one.

Comment: Indeed, you're right, I had not spotted that!

Answer (score -1):

You can use Newtonsoft to [parse to a JToken](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ParseJsonAny.htm) which will handle the typing for you, but with the downside of not having a stable and predictable class to deserialize to automatically

Then, you would want to check its type, which returns a [JTokenType enum](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_linq_jtokentype.htm)

Once you know what the underlying types are, marshal the data into your DTO classes

```cs
JToken responseJT = JToken.Parse(json); //json string

if (responseJT.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    //its an array, handle as needed ...
else if (responseJT.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    //its an object, handle as needed ...
```

Personally, I would keep the attachments property as a `List<Attachments>` and if the JToken has a JSON object I would just set it as the `[0]` index of that property. This way things stay consistent and you can use LINQ on that property with ease